# Conditionally performing a calculation based on a cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

This post is in search of a better solution to a problem I recently encountered. I found a solution, but I think there is a more efficient way to accomplish the operations.

I have a pandas dataframe created off a larger dataframe by using group by. The new df is for tracking responses for certain IDs. Reponses are either yes or no. Some ID's will have all one type of response, on the other, or a mix of the two, there is no pattern to whcih ID has which responses. Example pictured below:

[image: Dataframe Example]

I needed to get a total count of responses for each id. i.e. If a ID has only "Yes" or only "No" responses, it already has a total. If it has both I need to subtract the "No" responses from the "yes" values.

My initial solution was to split the yes and no rows into different dataframes, then merge on ID and create a new column subtracting the yes counts from the no counts. Code Below:

```
df = df_all.groupby(['ID', 'yes_no'].size().reset_index(name='count')

df_no = df[df['yes_no'] == "no"]
df_yes = df[df['yes_no'] == "yes"]

df_merge = pd.merge(df_no, df_yes, on = ('ID'), how = 'left')

df_merge['response_count'] = abs(df_merge['count_y'] - df_merge['count_x'])
```

Id love to use this as a chance to learn a better way to do this kind of operation.

Thank you!

Comment: What you want is unclear. Can you give a sample as a plain data and the expected output please?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is asking for alternative ways to create a dataframe showing the absolute value of the difference between yes and no responses by ID, here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_all = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID':[1028670, 1028670, 1028670, 1028676, 1028676, 1028676, 1028676, 1028676, 1028676, 1028678, 1028678, 1028678, 1028686, 1028686, 1028686, 1028688, 1028688, 1028688],
    'yes_no':['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']})
print(df_all)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(df_all['ID'])), columns=['ID'])
def calcResponseCount(row):
    dfWithId = df_all[df_all['ID'] == row['ID']]
    nYes, nNo = sum(dfWithId['yes_no'] == 'yes'), sum(dfWithId['yes_no'] == 'no')
    return abs(nYes - nNo)
df['response_count'] = df.apply(lambda x:calcResponseCount(x), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         ID yes_no
0   1028670    yes
1   1028670    yes
2   1028670     no
3   1028676    yes
4   1028676    yes
5   1028676    yes
6   1028676    yes
7   1028676    yes
8   1028676    yes
9   1028678    yes
10  1028678    yes
11  1028678    yes
12  1028686    yes
13  1028686     no
14  1028686     no
15  1028688    yes
16  1028688    yes
17  1028688    yes
        ID  response_count
0  1028676               6
1  1028678               3
2  1028686               1
3  1028688               3
4  1028670               1
```

Comment: @Antonio Volpini Does this answer do what you were asking? Do you need any more help?